# When a localization of a category is (non-)reflective?

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, localization

Let $S$ be a class of maps of a category $\mathcal{C}$. The [localization](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/localization) of $\mathcal{C}$ at $S$ is [reflective](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/reflective+localization) when the localization functor $\mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C}[S^{-1}]$ has a fully faithful right adjoint.

**Question 1:**

> Are there any general conditions on $S$ which imply that $\mathcal{C}[S^{-1}]$ is reflective?

Suppose that $\mathcal{C}$ is locally presentable and that $S$ is a small set. Then the full subcategory $\mathcal{C}$ consisting of $S$-local objects is reflective. Let $\widetilde{S}$ be the class of $S$-local maps. Then $S \subseteq \widetilde{S}$ and $\mathcal{C}[S^{-1}]$ is reflective if and only if $\mathcal{C}[S^{-1}] = \mathcal{C}[\widetilde{S}^{-1}]$.

**Question 2:**

> What are natural/useful examples of non-reflective localizations $\mathcal{C}[S^{-1}]$ (where $\mathcal{C}$ is locally presentable and $S$ is a set)?

The localization functor $\mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C}[\widetilde{S}^{-1}]$ satisfies a modified version of the universal property of $\mathcal{C}[S^{-1}]$. Namely, we require all functors in the definition of a localization to be left adjoints. This definition makes sense for an arbitrary category $\mathcal{C}$ and an arbitrary class of maps $S$.

**Question 3:**

> Is there a name for functors satisfying this universal property? Does it appear in the literature?

I want to call such a functor a *reflective localization* of $\mathcal{C}$ at $S$, but this terminology clashes with the ordinary notion of a reflective localization. Let us call it a *quasireflective localization* at $S$. Every reflective localization at $S$ is a quasireflective localization at $S$ by [this proposition](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/reflective+localization#ReflectionOntoLocalObjectsIsLocalizationWithRespectToLeftAdjoints), but a quasireflective localization at $S$ (if it exists) is a reflective localization at $\widetilde{S}$ rather than at $S$. Thus, we can ask a weaker version of Question 2:

**Question 2':**

> What are examples of quasireflective localizations at $S$ which are not reflective localizations at $S$.

Comment: As a natural example of non-reflective localization take $C=\mathrm{Ch}(\mathcal A)$, the chain complexes over a Grothendieck category, and $\mathcal S$, the class of quasi-isomorphisms. The corresponding localization is the derived category of $\mathcal A$ which is almost never contained in $\mathrm{Ch}(\mathcal A)$ as a full subcategory.

Comment: If $\mathcal A$ is a Grothendieck category, then $\mathrm{Ch}(\mathcal A)$ is locally $\alpha$-presentable (for a suitable choice of $\alpha$) and you can take $\mathcal S$ to be just the (small) set of quasi-isomorphisms among complexes where each term is $\alpha$-small.

Comment: @SimoneVirili Ah, indeed. I tihnk it is true more generally that the localization of many natural combinatorial model categories is not reflective.

Answer (score 4):

As a consequence of the main theorem in

> Di Liberti, I, and Loregian F.. "Homotopical algebra is not concrete." Journal of Homotopy and Related Structures (2017): 1-15.

(arXiv free version [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.00303)), that the homotopy category of "almost all" known model categories is not concrete, I claim that "almost all" model categories produce non-reflective localizations.

> **Proof**. All the examples we give in the paper are concrete categories (as a consequence of Remark 2.2, being concrete is a very weak assumption on a category); if you now assume $Ho(M)$ is a reflective localization of $M$, composing with a faithful functor $M \to Set$, you would get a faithful functor $Ho(M) \to M\to Set$.
>
> This contradicts our Theorem 4.8.

Answer (score 2):

My answer comments questions **Q1** and **Q2** and is connected to the fact that Fosco gave an answer to the case in which $\mathcal{K}[S^{-1}]$ is not concrete. I will try to cover the other case, when $\mathcal{K}[S^{-1}]$ is concrete. I claim that this is a very strong requirement on $S$.

When a cocomplete category is concrete, quite often it is also locally presentable (Top is the most famous counterexample to this statement, which is still quite true). Thus, imagine to have a locally presentable $\mathcal{K}[S^{-1}]$ for which such a faithful right adjoint exist.

$$L: \mathcal{K} \leftrightarrows \mathcal{K}[S^{-1}]: i $$

Since both the categories are locally presentable, $i$ must be accessible for a big enough cardinal (Thm 2.23 LPAC).

> **Thm.** An accessibly embedded reflective subcategory of a locally presentable category $\mathcal{A} \hookrightarrow \mathcal{K}$ is always of the form $\mathcal{K}[S^{-1}]$ for a small set $S$.

This result appears as Thm 1.39 in **Locally Presentable and Accessible categories**.

This means that quite often, the requirement for the existence of the faithful right adjoint is a strong requirement on the category $\mathcal{K}[S^{-1}]$, which in fact has to be equivalent to $\mathcal{K}[\bar{S}^{-1}]$ where $\bar{S}$ is (essentially) small.

May I conclude even that $\bar{S} \subset S$? *Probably yes*, in concrete examples $\bar{S}$ can even be chosen to lie inside $S$, this means that most of the information contained in $S$ is superfluous. This is due to  the structure of the proof of 1.39.

> All in all, putting together this answer with the other, the motto (which has no ambition of being a theorem) is: *either $S$ is small or  $\mathcal{K}[S^{-1}]$ is too big*.

Of course, this super-general motto, has many counterexample. The easiest one is when $\mathcal{K}$ is connected and $S$ is everything, in this case $\mathcal{K}[S^{-1}] \cong 1$, which is a quite *small* category. Thus, one should be careful when applying this motto, that still in real life examples will turn out to be quite true.

---

This argument can even be strengthened under Vopenka principle. In fact, under Vopenka every reflective subcategory of a locally presentable category must be locally presentable (Cor 6.24 LPAC), thus the *illegitimate upgrade* from concrete to locally presentable comes for free.